# openstack keystone command fails with internal server error 500 -- python Target WSGI script .. cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, openstack, keystone, openstack-keystone

when i tr to run this command in openstack controller node 
`openstack domain create --description "An Example Domain" example`
i get the error

```
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://controller1:35357/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)
```

this is my log that i think caused the problem but i can't fix it please help tanx:

```
2018-07-14 12:10:28.445646 mod_wsgi (pid=1549): Target WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin' cannot be loaded as Python module.
2018-07-14 12:10:28.445798 mod_wsgi (pid=1549): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin'.
2018-07-14 12:10:28.445841 Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-07-14 12:10:28.445880   File "/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin", line 54, in <module>
2018-07-14 12:10:28.445970     application = initialize_admin_application()
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446007   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 129, in initialize_admin_application
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446085     config_files=_get_config_files())
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446140   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 53, in initialize_application
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446186     common.configure(config_files=config_files)
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446235   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/common.py", line 28, in configure
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446294     keystone.conf.configure()
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446332   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/conf/__init__.py", line 125, in configure
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446394     help='Do not monkey-patch threading system modules.'))
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446450   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2440, in __inner
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446514     result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446568   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2654, in register_cli_opt
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446632     raise ArgsAlreadyParsedError("cannot register CLI option")
2018-07-14 12:10:28.446709 ArgsAlreadyParsedError: arguments already parsed: cannot register CLI option
2018-07-14 12:10:28.484261 mod_wsgi (pid=1555): Target WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin' cannot be loaded as Python module.
2018-07-14 12:10:28.484437 mod_wsgi (pid=1555): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin'.
2018-07-14 12:10:28.484505 Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-07-14 12:10:28.484653   File "/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin", line 54, in <module>
2018-07-14 12:10:28.484751     application = initialize_admin_application()
2018-07-14 12:10:28.484881   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 129, in initialize_admin_application
2018-07-14 12:10:28.485065     config_files=_get_config_files())
2018-07-14 12:10:28.485219   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 53, in initialize_application
2018-07-14 12:10:28.485351     common.configure(config_files=config_files)
2018-07-14 12:10:28.485417   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/common.py", line 28, in configure
2018-07-14 12:10:28.485545     keystone.conf.configure()
2018-07-14 12:10:28.485676   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/conf/__init__.py", line 125, in configure
2018-07-14 12:10:28.486396     help='Do not monkey-patch threading system modules.'))
2018-07-14 12:10:28.497029   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2440, in __inner
2018-07-14 12:10:28.498414     result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2018-07-14 12:10:28.498528   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2654, in register_cli_opt
2018-07-14 12:10:28.498636     raise ArgsAlreadyParsedError("cannot register CLI option")
2018-07-14 12:10:28.498948 ArgsAlreadyParsedError: arguments already parsed: cannot register CLI option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finnally found the solution 
in centOS 7 and all other distributions that have SELinux Enabled you should configure or completely Disable the SELinux to work

OpenStack queens

## CentOS 7

how to Disable permanently?
nano /etc/selinux/config

change two parameters to "disabled"